# c# WinForms - How to get the size of a UserControl set by the container form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building a WinForms UserControl. I have placed my items inside my new control and it has the "default" sizes that I have set up.

When placing my control inside of a form, I want to give it a different size in the form, and in the control itself I would like to get that size and work some logic in my control according to the size set in the Form itself. How can I access the size given by the WinForm?

If I use `this.Size.Width` I get the size set by the UserControl.

The only thing I have found is `AutoSize` - but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: this.Size is what you want.  I can only guess that you forgot to use the SizeChanged event so you can see the size changing.  Works at form design-time as well.

Comment: You can also override OnLayout. This method is called as soon as your UC is placed on the Form and also when the Layout changes (the UC is resized in the Form at Design-Time and Run-Time, for example).